# EmbeddedWB useragent not work in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: delphi, browser, delphi-7

I am using EmbeddedWB component in delphi 7. I changed useragent and it is work in windows XP, but user agent is not changed in windows 7 64 bit.
Do you know any idea?
Is there any other solution for specializing this custom browser for server?

Answer (score 1):

Example code to change UserAgent can be found here:

http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/changing-the-ua-user-agent-of-a-twebbrowser-component/